# Find the sum of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n5^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $$ \sum \limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n. 5^{n}}  $$ $$$$ I have tried in this way, the $ n^{th}$ term  of the series is $t_{n}=\frac{1}{n.5^{n}}$. Then $ S_{n}=t_{1}+t_{2}+.......+t_{n}$ But i can't proceed further , please anyone help me, thanks.

Comment: The goal of the exercise is most likely checking if you know by heart the series previously covered in class/in the book. So, I think there is a good chanche you can find the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n$ somewhere in your notes.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Consider the function:

\begin{align} f_n(x) = \sum\limits _{k=1}^n x^{k-1} =\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x} \end{align} 
Take the limits and integrate both sides and remember that the geometric series converges uniformly on interval $[a,b]$ provided that $-1<a<b<1$, so we get:
\begin{align}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int f_n(x) dx=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\int \sum\limits _{k=1}^n x^{k-1} dx=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int \frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x} dx\end{align}
We can take the limit inside the integral because of uniform convergence. 
\begin{align}  \int \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits _{k=1}^n x^{k-1} dx =  \int \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1} dx =   \int \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x} dx = \int \frac{1}{1-x} dx \end{align}
Now we get after integrating:
\begin{align} \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k}}{k}=-\ln(1-x)+C\end{align}
You get a integration constant $C$ so put    $x=0$ and solve for $C$. Put $x=1/5$ and your are done.

I made some edits to make it more understandable, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by expressing $1/n$ as $\int^1_0 x^{n-1} dx$

Comment: how to find the value

Answer (score 0):

HINT:$$-\ln(1-u)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{u^r}r$$

$$\dfrac1{n\cdot5^n}=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac15\right)^n}n$$